# What are some of the lowest melting point glasses available out there?

Tags: melting-point, glass

I'm wondering about lead-free "glass solder" or any glass frit powder or paste that has a very low melting point (under 400 c).  What products are available to the layman, where can I find them?

Comment: Standard suppliers include places like Schott.

Comment: Thanks, Im assuming this is the one: https://www.schott.com/en-gb/products/sealing-and-solder-glass/product-variants?tab=solder-glasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there are low softening-point (s.p.) silica-based glasses, such as [Anywhere Powder D235 and D240](https://www.anywherepowder.com/products/low-melting-point-glass-powder.html), with claimed s.p. of 350 °C and 400                       °C, respectively.

However, it's unlikely a glass would serve as solder. Unlike malleable metals, glass is strong, but *exceedingly brittle*. If the [coefficients of linear thermal expansion](https://www.us.schott.com/d/tubing/ffed51fb-ea4f-47d3-972e-5a2c20f123f5/1.2/schott-brochure-technical-glasses_us.pdf) of the two glasses *and* of the "solder" are not closely matched, then [the work will crack or shatter as it cools](http://www.davebross.com/GlassTech/glasscompatibility.html).

A standard test of the closeness of match of two types of glass is to [pull a combined thread from two glass rods](https://www.arrowsprings.com/html/stringer_test_for_compatibility.html). As the glass cools, if the two do *not* have matching coefficients, the combined thread will curl. Before you could meld glass, with or without a "solder", you'd need to confirm that all types expand and contract correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I was wondering about was if it was possible to add low melting point glass frit to a higher melting point light sensitive material, like a vat dye.  To make a photoceramic coating. Yes, to coat onto glass.

Comment: This need should, perhaps, be another question, with some more specifics, e.g., do you want *photosensitive glass*, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_glass , or *photochromic glass*, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/photochromic-glass, or some other effect, e.g., reproducing images , temporarily or permanently, in or on glass?

Comment: A non toxic, non dichromate, photoceramic method, whereby I could coat something on glass, expose, develop and fix, then fire: (it was you who helped me ;) https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150291/what-non-toxic-light-sensitive-materials-do-not-burn-away-at-high-heat  Not photosensitive glass, and not photochromic (unless there is a way to fix photochromic pigments). Maybe a better question is, what light sensitive materials have a high boiling point/melting point. Should I ask this question seperately?

Comment: @Curiousmarble, why not edit your question to fully explain your needs? Asking repeated simillar questions is likely to get them ignored or rejected. As for melting and boiling points, another important question might be **stability** at high temperature.

Comment: I have re-answered you on the original question.